# How to use Machine Alias in RMI server

Tags: java, rmi

I am running my rmi server on a machine thats part of a cluster. The IP is likely to change and therfore connecting via this process is not reliable.

Uo until now on the dev box at work having a connection based on the IP was fine but moving to UAT i need to change it and I dont know how.

Below I have the code for the server and the client classes. Here you can see i use the machine ip to connect. How do i replaces this with the machine alias? Is this possible or am I getting confused?

Thanks

```
private final String address = "111.111.111.111";
private Registry registry;
private int port = 6789;
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RmiServer.class);

public RmiServer() throws RemoteException {
    try {
        registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
        registry.rebind("rmiServer", this);
        logger.info("Server is Ready! Connected on: " + address + ":" + port + " ." +
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        logger.error("Unable to start the server. Exiting the application.", e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}

private final String serverAddress = "111.111.111.111";
private String serverPort = "6789";
private ReceiveMessageInterface rmiServer;
private Registry registry;
private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RMIClient.class);

public RMIClient(){
    try {
        registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(serverAddress, (new Integer(serverPort)).intValue());
        rmiServer = (ReceiveMessageInterface) (registry.lookup("rmiServer"));

        logger.info("Client started correctly");
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        logger.error("Remote object exception occured when connecting to server. Exiting application", e);
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (NotBoundException e) {
        logger.error("Not Bound Exception occured when connecting to server. Exiting application", e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you're asking what you have to do to the server to export stubs with the correct IP address in them, that's what the `java.rmi.server.hostname` property is for. Set it to the desired hostname or IP address in the server JVM before exporting any Registries or remote objects.
2. If you're asking how to let the clients know where the Registry is after the server changes its IP address, there is no single accepted solution. You could have the server multicast its IP address periodically, or adopt some sneakernet method.